Can we enable code coverage while the api is running NOT while running Munits
while this is not a question about any specific code , am wondering if there is a way that we can enable code coverage after the api is deployed and QA team is testing functionality
The way we get code coverage reports when we perform munits
At this moment even if performance is poor , am fine with that but the real purpose is to check once testing signs off or even while they are testing , to check if all branches of code were executed / covered ?
This is for Mule 4.x

At this time Mule 4.x flow coverage is only implemented as a feature for MUnit tests.

thanks am hoping this could be a useful feature that mule adds !

It is not supported with MUnits yet. However, What you are describing is integration tests. The goal of such a test is not to test the cover the code, but to cover as many business cases as you can test. I will suggest not considering code coverage as a metric of in this case.
Integration tests are performed from user's perspective unlike unit tests which are performed from Developer's perspective. Focus on the usage situations from the user perspective. Once you have that increase your business "coverage" by adding in edge cases to your tests.

thanks and agree with your comments , you know we have choice routers and then also if else conditions in our dataweave , so in addition to business cases it would be nice ( additional confidence ) if we could have seen if the test hit those areas of code :)
